# Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in nav-menu-template.php

Tags: plugins, navigation

I installed new template (increased max and post fields) and after that the site shows in main page an error:

> **Warning**: sprintf(): Too few arguments in nav-menu-template.php

What should I check? If I get back to the older template the error still exist (it was not before).

Comment: can you provide the full error?

Comment: yes. Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /home/<websitename>/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php

Comment: Ahh, I was hoping it'd show the line number. But it turns out there's only 1x `sprintf()` in that file. What you do mean exactly by "installed new template (increased max and post fields)"? You activated a new theme? If you're still getting an error, then the change that caused the problem likely wasn't the theme change. Instead you've probably changed something else along the way without being aware... can you think of anything?

Comment: Line 291. I edit php.ini post max size and upload max size and thats it.